# Alternatives to Silverlight and WCF Ria Services for LOS Business Applications

Tags: wcf-ria-services

Currently, what are the competing products for silverlight and wcf ria services for building los business applications? Thank for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at http://www.ideablade.com/DevForceSilverlight/DevForceSilverlight_overview.aspx